# Cannot perform CREATE TABLE using Liquibase update for Snowflake as this session does not have a current database?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, liquibase, snowflake-schema

I am trying to run Snowflake update using Liquibase as the following command which has fully qualified name of the server, database and the schema.

`liquibase --username=myusername --password=mypassword --url="jdbc:snowflake://myserver-name-europe.azure.snowflakecomputing.com/?db=mydb&schema=public" --changelog-file=/samplechangelog.snowflake.sql update`

But it just gives me error that I didn't specify the database which I did.
Also, the same command work with other Snowflake account? I just even copy and paste it from other project, it's just the name of the server URL and DB is the different.

Here is the error message:

`Unexpected error running Liquibase: Cannot perform CREATE TABLE. This session does not have a current database. Call 'USE DATABASE', or use a qualified name. [Failed SQL: (90105) CREATE TABLE DATABASECHANGELOGLOCK (ID INT NOT NULL, LOCKED BOOLEAN NOT NULL, LOCKGRANTED TIMESTAMP_NTZ, LOCKEDBY VARCHAR(255), CONSTRAINT PK_DATABASECHANGELOGLOCK PRIMARY KEY (ID))]`

[image]

Comment: Does Liquibase have an option to specify a database and schema in the connection string?  If not, you should assign a default namespace for the user that you are using to connect from liquibase with:  https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/alter-user.html

Comment: You could also fully qualify your table with database and schema in your CREATE TABLE statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest setting up a default role for user "username":

```
ALTER USER myusername SET DEFAULT_ROLE = my_default_role;
```

If user does not have default warehouse assigned then:

```
ALTER USER myusername SET DEFAULT_WAHREOUSE = my_warehouse_name;
```

It is also possible to set dabatabase/schema/warehouse/... in `db.properties` file. Related: [Specifying Properties in a Connection Profile](https://docs.liquibase.com/concepts/connections/creating-config-properties.html)

Answer (score 1):

This error is usually due to insufficient permissions - if the user cannot 'see' the database, liquibase silently sets it to null and then fails with this error. The best method of troubleshooting this is to connect via Snowflake web GUI with the same credentials (without setting any role or warehouse), then try running 'use database ...'.
The solution is to grant enough permissions to the user - either directly or via a role (but then the role name needs to be passed on in the jdbc connection string as well).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the issue was in the permissions for the current user that I am trying to use to connect to the Snowflake, here what I did:

```
ALTER USER myuser SET DEFAULT_ROLE=SYSADMIN
```

This lead to another error as there is no active warehouse, so I set the whorehouse in the connection string of the JDBC driver as the following:

`liquibase --username=myusername --password=mypassword --url="jdbc:snowflake://myserver-name-europe.azure.snowflakecomputing.com/?&warehouse=COMPUTE_WH&db=mydb&schema=public"--changelog-file=/samplechangelog.snowflake.sql update`

So, I can send any values in the connection string for the JDBC as the following:

`jdbc:snowflake://myorganization-myaccount.snowflakecomputing.com/?user=peter&warehouse=mywh&db=mydb&schema=public`

Here is the page for more info about JDBC driver connection string:

[JDBC connection string to Snowflake](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/jdbc-configure.html)

Comment: Another option could be setting default WAREHOUSE `ALTER USER myusername SET DEFAULT_WAHREOUSE = COMPUTE` at user level